How to import connected Entries with FeedMe
I am having trouble importing a list of connected entries via FeedMe.  I have several "Summary" entries that are connected to several "WHA" entries each.  I have this test JSON script that appears correct, but I keep getting a "null" error in the FeedMe logs.
{
  "summary": [
    {
      "summary title":"Summary-1",
      "connected whas": {
        "wha title": [
          "WHA_TITLE": "WHA-9-097",
          "WHA_TITLE": "WHA-9-098"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

The error I'm getting in FeedMe: craft\feedme\base\Element::parseTitle(): Return value must be of type string, null returned - Element.php: 303
I'm not entirely understanding why I'm getting this error as this data is in a string?
Thanks for any help.
